# How to convert rows of questions and answers to single row with columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel 365 (2016) file that contains rows of questions/answers that I need converted to columns as shown below.

[image: Sample Excel]

```
Person  Question    Answer      
Bob     Dogs Name   Rover       
Bob     Cats Name   Mewl        
Bob     Car Type    Mustang     
Bob     Own/Rent    Own     
Carol   Cats Name   Tiger       
Carol   Car Type    Ford        
Carol   Own/Rent    Rent        
Ted Own/Rent    Own     
Alice   Dogs Name   Growler     
Alice   Cats Name   Cali        
Alice   Car Type    GMC     
Alice   Own/Rent    Own     


       Dogs Name    Cats Name   Car Type    Own/Rent
Bob    Rover        Mewl        Mustang     Own
Carol               Tiger       Ford        Rent
Ted                                         Own
Alice   Growler     Cali        GMC         Own
```

Comment: [This](https://exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match) may be useful

Comment: [related](https://superuser.com/q/1274325/670755)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Power Query get the result:

1. Select range- Go to Data- From Range/Table:
   [image]
2. Select Question Column- go to Transform tab- Select Pivot Column- Values Column select Answer- Advanced options select Don't Aggreate:
   [image]
3. Close and Load:
   [image]

Comment: This was a perfect answer and it efficiently gave me the steps to do exactly what I needed! Thanks for a great response.

Answer (score 1):

in order to get your column and row headers, you need to generate a list of unique entries.  This can be achieved formulaicly, you can manually type it out or you can use a built in tool in the ribbon called text to columns:

[image: remove duplicates]

Step 1

Copy the range you want unique values from to a separate area. Then select the copied list:

[image: select columns]

Step 2

Select Remove Duplicates from ribbon

[image: remove duplicates]

Step 3

Click the "My data has headers" in the upper right if applicable to your range, and then select ok

[image: OK]

Step 4

Repeat Steps 1 to 3 for the other column

[image: other column]

Step 5

Transpose the unique column that you want to use for column headers.  Select the column you want to transpose. right click and select copy:

[image: copy]

Select the location where the first cell of the header row is to be.  In this example H1.  Right click and under the paste choices, select transpose:

[image: Transpose]

Step 7

Fill in the table.  Base on the examples that I have been showing, in H2 enter the following formula and copy it down and right to fill in the table:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($A$2:$A$13)/(($A$2:$A$13=$G2)*($B$2:$B$13=H$1)),1)),"")
```

[image: end result]

AGGREGATE with formula choice 14 performs array operations within its brackets.  As a result do not use full column references within these brackets.  NOTE the $C:$C is outside the AGGRGRATE function where it is safe to use full column references.

There are other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is called a Pivot Table.  This function can take repeated data from one or more columns and pivot it to become a header.

All modern spreadsheet programs use that name for this function, but each one handles it slightly differently.  Microsoft provides an introduction to this function in your specific application:
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: 1. this does not answer the question, just gives a hint. 2. pivot table won't be useful here as it can't work well correctly with text (only show count  or distinct count of items, but can't show the text itself).